# Pytest Fixture to use sqlite file based DB for test?

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-settings, pytest-django

I'm using `pytest` and `pytest-django` to test a Django project.

I have `test_settings.py` that I use in order to use in-memory databases. It is very simple and looks like this:

```
from .settings import *

# Set up in memory databases for testing purposes
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
    },
    "other_db": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
    },
}
```

My `pytest.ini` is equally simple:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = ic_project.test_settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

There are a few spots where I would like to test using an actual `.sqlite3` file - not in memory.

So I tried writing the following fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def file_based_db(settings):
    """Generator to create a file based database for testing"""
    settings.DATABASES["default"]["TEST"] = {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": "default_db.sqlite3",
    }

    settings.DATABASES["other_db"]["TEST"] = {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": "other_db.sqlite3",
    }
```

So a test I'd like to use this 'file_based_db' on would look something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("file_based_db")
class ThingForm(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.thing = Thing.objects.create(name="thing1")

    def test_empty_form_fields(self):
        form = MyForm()
        self.assertIn("created_by", form.fields)
        self.assertIn("deleted_at", form.fields)
        self.assertIn("updated_by", form.fields)
        breakpoint()
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
    return [
        alias for alias in connections
        if alias in cls.databases and (
>           include_mirrors or not connections[alias].settings_dict['TEST']['MIRROR']
        )
    ]
E   KeyError: 'MIRROR'
```

Ultimately as you can see, I'm just trying to add the "TEST" database dictionary to the `settings.DATABASES` - but I only want that in certain cases.

If there are other ways to do this? I'm happy to hear about how - I thought a pytest fixture would work great so I could just decorate the few tests where I wanted that.

Any help would be appreciated - as I'm not sure what `KeyError: 'MIRROR'` is referring to.